# Google Maps on iOS Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, maps, ios-simulator

I'm building an iOS app that I want to interact with the Native maps application that comes on iPhone & iPad. No maps application seems to be installed on either of the simulators.

How can I test this functionality on the iOS simulator?

---

When I let Google Maps website take over with the following url

http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=37.785834,-122.406417

This happens

[image]

Comment: How do you want to interact with the maps app? The only thing you can do is link to a location that opens in Maps.

Comment: I want to have several buttons and each button would open a link showing directions from your current location to the linked location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) (link now dead) used to say:

> If the Maps application is not installed on the device, opening a map URL forwards the request to the Google Maps website.

So you *can* test this in the simulator, but it will open in Safari instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
[someUIApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London"]]
```

This will open the maps app from apple.

**NOTE: THIS ONLY WORKS ON THE DEVICE ITSELF. NOT IN THE SIMULATOR.**

It's one of the "missing" features of the simulator.

Like Woz said, it will open on safari, not in the native app.